# tablesorter not sorting

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Sorry for coming with this dumb question, but I've been struggling for hours without success.
My sample table is not being sorted. Both .js files are located in the same directory as the .shtml file itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
   <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Test1</th>
     <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1622</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>2634</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have bad copies of jquery and tablesorter? It appears to work fine for me using the actual versions of both jquery and tablesorter linked from their respective sites.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
   <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Test1</th>
     <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1622</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>2634</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid there must be a general config problem. The sources you provided are not working either...

Comment: Yea, not sure then. This worked for me on both Chrome and IE8, but I did have to allow the scripts in IE8.

Comment: Be sure to use [this fork](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) of tablesorter. It fixes all sorts of issues with the original, which hasn't bee updated for several years now.